# Problem with landscape table possibly related to Package scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: tables, landscape, scrlayer-scrpage

Hello: I'm trying to execute a master file with landscape tables in the included file (\include{...}). The master file always stops executing and prints in the console output and error:

```
> Output loop---1000 consecutive dead cycles. \clearpage ...rite \m@ne
> {}\vbox {}\penalty -\@Mi                                                  
> l.232 \end{landscape}
```

**There are also the following warnings:**

```
> Package scrlayer-scrpage Warning: \headheight to low. At least
> 23.99747pt needed, but only 18.125pt found. I'll enlarge \headheight, for further processing, but you should do this yourself, e.g., setting
> typearea's option headheight=23.99747pt'. I'll also decrease
> \topmargin on input line 20. Package scrlayer-scrpage Warning:
> \footheight to low. At least 23.99747pt needed, but only 18.125pt
> found. I'll enlarge \footheight, for further processing, but you
> should do this yourself, e.g., setting typearea's option
> footheight=23.99747pt'. I'll also increase \footskip on input line 20.
```

**And several overfull \hbox as below:**

```
> Overfull \hbox (3.99596pt too wide) detected at line 14
```

I used to be able to execute the same file without problems on a Mac with `\usepackage{scrpage2}` instead of `\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}`. I recently switched to a PC.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

MWE from master file:

```
    \documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrbook} 
    \pagestyle{plain}    
    \usepackage{adjustbox}    
    \usepackage{pdflscape}     
    \usepackage{tabulary}    
    \usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}     
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}    
    \usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}    
    \usepackage{threeparttable}
    
    \let\estinput=\input 

    \newcommand{\estwide}[3]{
        \vspace{.75ex}{
            \textsymbols% Note the added command here
            \begin{tabular*}
            {\textwidth}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{#2}{#3}}
            \toprule
            \estinput{#1}
            \bottomrule
            \addlinespace[.75ex]
            \end{tabular*}
            }
        }   

    \newcommand{\estauto}[3]{
        \vspace{-0.75ex}{
            \textsymbols% Note the added command here
            \begin{tabular}{l*{#2}{#3}}
            \toprule
            \estinput{#1}
            \bottomrule
            \addlinespace[.75ex]
            \end{tabular}
            }
        }

    \newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}
    }

    \newcommand{\Figtext}[1]{%
        \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
        \hspace{6pt}
        \hangindent=1.75em
        #1
        \end{tablenotes}
        }
    \newcommand{\Fignote}[1]{\Figtext{\emph{Note:~}~#1}}
    \newcommand{\Figsource}[1]{\Figtext{\emph{Source:~}~#1}}
    \newcommand{\Starnote}{\Figtext{* p < 0.1, ** p < 0.05, *** p<0.01. Standard errors in parentheses.}}
    
    \maxdeadcycles=1000\relax
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{onehalfspacing}
    
     \section*{Intro}

     Lots of text. This first table below, which executes without problems (does not use landscape). 

    \begin{table}\centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Table 1: Descriptive statistics for public state investment per capita (DV)}
    \estwide{descriptive_stats3_Mexico}{5}{l}
   \end{threeparttable}
   \end{table}

More text.

    \vspace{-10 mm}
    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}\centering
      \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{Table 2: Benchmark regression}
           \estauto{table2_benchmark.tex}{1}{S[table-format=0.7,table-column-width=15mm]}
    \starnotes
      \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
    \end{landscape}

    \vspace{-10 mm}
    \begin{landscape}
   \begin{table}\centering
   \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Table A.1: Results replicated with outliers included}
       \estauto{tablea1_robust_outliers_included.tex}{5}{S[table-format=0.7,table-column-width=15mm]}
   \starnotes
   \end{threeparttable}
   \end{table}
   \end{landscape}

   \section*{Conclusion}

   More text. 
 
    \bibliographystyle{apacite}  
    \bibliography{library}
    
    \newpage
    
    \theendnotes
    
    \end{document}
```

---

Here's file table2_benchmark.tex.

```
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\specialcell{Public investment\\ per capita}}\\
\midrule
FDI shock           &     155.671\sym{***}\\
                    &    (30.654)         \\
L.invest\_cap        &       0.443\sym{***}\\
                    &     (0.054)         \\
L.invest\_cap        &                     \\
                    &                     \\
L.invest\_eg         &                     \\
                    &                     \\
Total federal transfers per capita&       0.060\sym{***}\\
                    &     (0.014)         \\
State taxes per capita&      -0.042         \\
                    &     (0.058)         \\
Real GDP per capita &                     \\
                    &                     \\
Real GDP growth (percent)&      13.107\sym{**} \\
                    &     (5.211)         \\
Population density  &       2.760\sym{**} \\
                    &     (1.084)         \\
PRI governor        &     145.110\sym{***}\\
                    &    (46.721)         \\
PAN governor        &     210.092\sym{***}\\
                    &    (57.322)         \\
Election year dummy &    -155.691\sym{***}\\
                    &    (34.424)         \\
\midrule
Observations        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{571}         \\
\(R^{2}\)           &\multicolumn{1}{S}{0.683}         \\
```

This one above is only one column, but I have some wider 5 column tables that I'd like to include using landscape, such as the one below.

```
Name: tablea1_robust_outliers_included.tex

                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\specialcell{Public investment\\ per capita}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\specialcell{Public investment\\ per capita}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\specialcell{Current spending\\ per capita}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\specialcell{Public debt\\ per capita}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\specialcell{Public debt\\ /real GDP}}\\
\midrule
FDI shock           &     149.696\sym{***}&                     &    -130.202\sym{**} &    -237.688\sym{**} &      -0.002\sym{***}\\
                    &    (51.078)         &                     &    (59.197)         &    (92.431)         &     (0.001)         \\
                    FDI shock (1.5 std deviations)         &                     &     154.018\sym{**} &                     &                     &                     \\
                    &                     &    (64.110)         &                     &                     &                     \\
Total federal transfers per capita&       0.066\sym{***}&       0.065\sym{***}&       0.154\sym{***}&      -0.116\sym{***}&      -0.000\sym{**} \\
                    &     (0.025)         &     (0.025)         &     (0.029)         &     (0.039)         &     (0.000)         \\
Total public federal investment per capita&      -0.000\sym{**} &      -0.000\sym{**} &       0.000\sym{***}&      -0.000         &      -0.000         \\
                    &     (0.000)         &     (0.000)         &     (0.000)         &     (0.000)         &     (0.000)         \\
State taxes per capita&      -0.047         &      -0.040         &       0.167         &       2.010\sym{***}&       0.000\sym{***}\\
                    &     (0.142)         &     (0.141)         &     (0.144)         &     (0.517)         &     (0.000)         \\
Real GDP per capita &       0.000         &       0.000         &      -0.000         &       0.002\sym{***}&       0.000\sym{***}\\
                    &     (0.000)         &     (0.000)         &     (0.000)         &     (0.001)         &     (0.000)         \\
Real GDP growth (percent)&      11.786         &      12.115         &      16.945\sym{**} &       2.240         &      -0.000         \\
                    &     (8.278)         &     (8.296)         &     (7.141)         &     (8.502)         &     (0.000)         \\
Population density  &       3.641\sym{**} &       3.890\sym{**} &       5.243\sym{***}&     -11.485\sym{***}&      -0.000\sym{***}\\
                    &     (1.777)         &     (1.735)         &     (1.181)         &     (2.576)         &     (0.000)         \\
PRI governor        &     146.660\sym{**} &     137.884\sym{**} &      -7.245         &    -426.912\sym{***}&      -0.002\sym{**} \\
                    &    (60.630)         &    (59.728)         &    (75.797)         &   (150.507)         &     (0.001)         \\
PAN governor        &     219.231\sym{***}&     210.680\sym{***}&     -59.692         &    -157.941         &      -0.000         \\
                    &    (65.856)         &    (65.447)         &    (87.952)         &   (131.951)         &     (0.001)         \\
Election year dummy &    -153.171\sym{***}&    -156.498\sym{***}&      43.552         &      43.280         &       0.000         \\
                    &    (44.702)         &    (45.075)         &    (49.376)         &    (54.645)         &     (0.001)         \\
Margin of victory for state governor&     -21.669         &     -41.144         &     133.284         &     792.233         &       0.011\sym{***}\\
                    &   (183.507)         &   (179.794)         &   (215.383)         &   (428.729)         &     (0.004)         \\
\midrule
Observations        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{558}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{558}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{558}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{558}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{558}         \\
\(R^{2}\)           &\multicolumn{1}{S}{0.683}         &\multicolumn{1}{S}{0.679}         &\multicolumn{1}{S}{0.988}         &\multicolumn{1}{S}{0.634}         &\multicolumn{1}{S}{0.552}         \\
```

Comment: Where is defined command `\estauto`?

Comment: Please, make your document example compilable. Insert `corruptionpaper` in the main document and provide all your definition. As provided code fragments are, is impossible to help you.

Comment: there is no example here that shows the problem, but why `\vspace{` just before `\begin{landscape}` (which always forces a new page?

Comment: @Zarko, I have included the command \estauto now and the main parts of the corruptionpaper file. David, I tried removing the \vspace{} but that didn't work. I don't know exactly why I included it (I assume to make sure the table drops down from the top margin) and I had it included originally when I was able to execute the file. Let me know what else I can provide. Thanks.

Comment: Your code is still not compilable.  Missed are definition for `\estinput`, etc. Please merge both code fragments in one complete document as I ask in my previous comment that we can compile it.

Comment: Where is `table2_benchmark.tex`? Also seems to be missed some packages. Please test your code before you publish here and see, if it is complete.

Comment: @Zarko, I've tried to address those and paste all info. The code used to work. The problem started when I switched to a PC and downloaded new software.

Comment: Sorry but frankly said, the provided code newer works! Mised are packages, definitions and some `tex` files etc.  Due to this, we cant reach your problem (if it exist after all) . Please again, make from your fragments **one complete**, tested file, which include all your sub-files  and which reproduce your problem with `landscape` pages, which we can copy and test in our computers as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Provided code is erroneous and consequently not useful.
- The `scrpage2` package is obsolete, instead it is better to use `scrlayer-scrpage` package (which in my MWE works  fine).
- From code fragments I form the MWE (Minimal Working Example) with merging relevant code fragments, which should reproduce your problem.
- From table code also follows that it is bigger than text area on landscape page.
- To fit table on the page, I suggest to use smaller font size and reduce `\arraystertch` (see MWE below).

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrbook}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx, threeparttable}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand\StErr{%
    \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
    \item[*]    $p < 0.1$,
    \item[**]   $p < 0.05$,
    \item[***]  $p < 0.01$. Standard errors in parentheses.
    \end{tablenotes}
                }

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section*{Intro}

\lipsum[11]
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Descriptive statistics for public state investment per capita (DV)}
\label{tab:statistic}
\begin{tabular}{lS[input-open-uncertainty= ,
                  input-close-uncertainty= ,
                  table-space-text-pre=(,
                  table-space-text-post={***},
                  table-align-text-pre=false,
                  table-format=-3.3]}
    \toprule
    & {\makecell{Public investment\\ per capita}}\\
    \midrule
FDI shock           &  155.671\tnote{***}   \\
                    &  (30.654)             \\
L.invest\_cap       &    0.443\tnote{***}   \\
                    &   (0.054)             \\
L.invest\_cap       &                       \\
                    &                       \\
L.invest\_eg        &                       \\
                    &                       \\
Total federal transfers per capita
                    &    0.060\tnote{***}   \\
                    &   (0.014)             \\
State taxes per capita
                    &   -0.042              \\
                    &   (0.058)             \\
Real GDP per capita &                       \\
                    &                       \\
Real GDP growth (percent)
                    &   13.107\tnote{**}    \\
                    &   (5.211)             \\
Population density  &    2.760\tnote{**}    \\
                    &   (1.084)             \\
PRI governor        &  145.110\tnote{***}   \\
                    &  (46.721)             \\
PAN governor        &  210.092\tnote{***}   \\
                    &  (57.322)             \\
Election year dummy & -155.691\tnote{***}   \\
                    &  (34.424)             \\
\midrule
Observations        & {571}                 \\
\(R^{2}\)           & {0.683}               \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\StErr
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}

\afterpage{
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \small
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.8}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Benchmark regression}
\label{tab:benchmark}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X 
                             *{5}{S[input-open-uncertainty= ,   
                                    input-close-uncertainty= , 
                                    table-space-text-pre=(,    
                                    table-space-text-post={***}, 
                                    table-align-text-pre=false,
                                    table-format=-3.3]}
                             }
    \toprule
    &   {\makecell[b]{PI\\ per capita}}
        &   {\makecell[b]{PI\\ per capita}}
            &   {\makecell[b]{CS\\ per capita}}
                &   {\makecell[b]{Public debt\\ per capita}}
                    &   {\makecell[b]{Public debt/\\ real GDP}}\\
    \midrule
FDI shock           
    & 149.696\tnote{***}    
        &   & -130.202\tnote{**} 
                & -237.688\tnote{**} 
                    & -0.002\tnote{***}     \\
    & (51.078)      
        &   & (59.197)      
                & (92.431)
                    &   (0.001)             \\  \addlinespace
FDI shock (1.5 std deviations)         
    &   & 154.018\tnote{**} 
            &   &   &                       \\
    &   &  (64.110)     
            &   &   &                       \\  \addlinespace
Total federal transfers per capita
    & 0.066\tnote{***}   
        &  0.065\tnote{***} 
            & 0.154\tnote{***}   
                & -0.116\tnote{***}
                    & -0.000\tnote{**}      \\
    & (0.025)         
        &  (0.025)
            & (0.029) 
                & (0.039)     
                    & (0.000)               \\  \addlinespace
Total public federal investment per capita
    &  -0.000\tnote{**} 
        & -0.000\tnote{**}   
            & 0.000\tnote{***} 
                & -0.000   
                    & -0.000                \\
    &  (0.000)     
        & (0.000)      
            & (0.000)    
                & (0.000) 
                    & (0.000)               \\  \addlinespace
State taxes per capita
    &  -0.047  
        & -0.040   
            & 0.167  
                & 2.010\tnote{***} 
                    & 0.000\tnote{***}      \\
    &  (0.142)        
        & (0.141) 
            & (0.144) 
                & (0.517)       
                    & (0.000)               \\  \addlinespace
Real GDP per capita 
    &  0.000          
        & 0.000    
            & -0.000 
                & 0.002\tnote{***} 
                    & 0.000\tnote{***}      \\
    & (0.000)         
        & (0.000)  
            & (0.000)
                & (0.001) 
                    & (0.000)               \\  \addlinespace
Real GDP growth (percent)
    &  11.786         
        & 12.115   
            & 16.945\tnote{**} 
                & 2.240  
                    & -0.000                \\
    & (8.278)         
        & (8.296)   
            & (7.141)         
                & (8.502)
                    & (0.000)               \\  \addlinespace
Population density  
    & 3.641\tnote{**} 
        & 3.890\tnote{**} 
            & 5.243\tnote{***}
                & -11.485\tnote{***}
                    & -0.000\tnote{***}     \\
    & (1.777)         
        & (1.735)
            & (1.181)        
                & (2.576)         
                    & (0.000)               \\  \addlinespace
PRI governor       
    &  146.660\tnote{**} 
        & 137.884\tnote{**} 
            & -7.245         
                & -426.912\tnote{***}
                    & -0.002\tnote{**}      \\ 
    &  (60.630)         
        & (59.728)         
            & (75.797)         
                & (150.507)         
                    &  (0.001)              \\  \addlinespace
PAN governor        
    & 219.231\tnote{***}
        & 210.680\tnote{***}
            & -59.692        
                & -157.941         
                    & -0.000                \\
    & (65.856)        
        & (65.447)         
            & (87.952)         
                & (131.951)         
                    & (0.001)               \\  \addlinespace[2pt]
Election year dummy 
    & -153.171\tnote{***}
        & -156.498\tnote{***}
            & 43.552         
                & 43.280         
                    & 0.000                 \\
    & (44.702)         
        & (45.075)         
            & (49.376)         
                & (54.645)         
                    & (0.001)               \\  \addlinespace[2pt]
Margin of victory for state governor
    &  -21.669   
        & -41.144     
            & 133.284  
                & 792.233    
                    &   0.011\tnote{***}    \\
    & (183.507)
        & (179.794) 
            & (215.383) 
                & (428.729)  
                    & (0.004)               \\
    \midrule
Observations        
    & {558} & {558} & {558} & {558} & {558} \\
\(R^{2}\)           
    & 0.683 & 0.679 &       &       &       \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}    
    \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
    PI: Public investment, \quad
    CS: Current spending
    
    \item[*]    $p < 0.1$, 
    \item[**]   $p < 0.05$, 
    \item[***]  $p < 0.01$. Standard errors in parentheses.
    \end{tablenotes} 
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
}
\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```

which produce:

[image]

In MWE you can observe, that

- In MWE are considered only packages and definitions relevant to your problem
- I didn't consider your (erroneous) definition of commands. If you like to have table codes in separate files, than you can store tables body (all between `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` in file with name "tablea1_robust_outliers_included" and include it in main file as follows:

```
    \begin{table}[ht]
\input{tablea1_robust_outliers_included}
    \end{table}
```

- Rename (to `\StErr`) and redesign command for insert table notes in `threeparttable`. Its works is demonstrated in the first table
- Redesign `S` column specification that now it works
- Replace `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` and `\specialcell` with `\makecell` macro defined in the `makecell` package (which is in MWE added in preamble)
- You can observe, that my MWE hasn't any problem with using the `scrlayer-scrpage` package and influence on position table on landscape page.

**Edit:**

In the first version of MWE I forgot to add caption to the first table and didn't correct caption text, where are words "Table 1:" and "Table 2:" superfluous (they are already generated by command `\caption`).

Beside these changes is now added package `afterpage` which enable better formatting of document.

Comment: I was able to get this to compile correctly by changing the lines of code above \begin{threeparttable}, which was: \begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \small
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.8}
\begin{threeparttable}

Comment: @Zack, Sorry, I don't understand your comment.  This code line, for which you say, that you change, are already in provided MWE (i.e., you not change anything). Now  I only see, that in the first table I forgot to add caption. This is corrected now.